# Has there been a change in the tag wiki editing privileges policy?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, policy

> You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

Oddly enough, the wiki in question is https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mootools/info — which I both created and maintained through editing just fine until I just tried to update it again today.

What has changed in policy? As there was nobody else who had sufficient rep points for the [mootools](/questions/tagged/mootools) tag, does this it mean we are going to be unable to update it unless it gets moderated or somebody else gains enough rep for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, the rule changed overnight (for US time zones, anyways). The old one was too confusing, I guess.

> Privilege changes: Create tags has been raised from 150 to 300. Retag has been raised from 200 to 500. A new 5k privilege to approve or reject tag wiki edits has been added. A new 15k privilege to protect a question has been added. The question must be older than a day. You can also un-protect a question you protected, but not one that has been protected by someone else. **The requirements for editing a tag wiki have been simplified to a 20k rep privilege.**

Emphasis mine. Source: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446)

Comment: Oh cheers. So, essentially, direct tag-based rep (gained through a particular tag) no longer has the same clout and you just need 20k rep. That's all very fine when you get 10s and 10s of questions a day but for smaller ones like #mootools with 10 a week, wikis/ editing are becoming more difficult.

Comment: @Dimitar, I agree. Except, people still can propose edits I believe.  So you can still propose edits to tag wikis, and 5k+ people can approve them.